# cant fetch value of dropdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down select menu and i want to store the selected value in the controller.i.e If office1 is selected then Office! is selected in the scope and so.
I am unable to store the value in the controller as I am new to angularjs.Can somebody Help
Heres my dropdown code

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
<h5>Select the System:</h5>

   <select id="repeatSystem" ng-model="selectedSystem" style="width: 100%">
    <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in systems" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>

 <select id="repeatOffice" ng-model="selectedState" style="width: 100%">
    <option ng-repeat="system in systems[selectedSystem]" value="state">{{system}}</option>
</select>

</div>
```

here is the plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/nNsM4VMVeHXS2hDIsAAd?p=preview

Comment: It matters when you want to get value in controller??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are binding select dropdown with `ng-model` then you can simply access these value in your controller.

This will give you first dropdown selected value

```
$scope.selectedSystem //same in view {{selectedSystem}}
```

This is for second

```
$scope.selectedState //same in view {{selectedState}}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0xPWHUSOwhtX4LGuV1q?p=preview) select value and check.

---

**Updates**

I have updated this following line, where you had hardcoded `value="state"` to i changed it to `value="{{state}}"`:

```
<option ng-repeat="state in result[selectedArea]" value="{{state}}">{{state}}</option>
```

See Updated [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMMM2CbFd0pi9AZOBv25?p=preview)

Comment: I also want to add that he should change the `value="state"` to `value="{{state}}"` or to`ng-value="state"`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do explain it more.

Comment: In the second select with `id="repeatOffice"`, all options would have the value which is "state" rather than the actual value for each state. and I don't think that's what the OP wants. To get the actual value of the selected item, `value="state"` should be changed to `value="{{state}}"` or to `ng-value="state"`

Comment: @Dola got this point updated answer and added information. I believe this is what OP want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about how to answer the question. The value of the drop-downs in the controller will be bound to the variables:

`$scope.selectedArea` and `$scope.selectedState` depending on what values are selected in the view. The value attribute that you're setting is overriding it however.

I've updated your plunkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/F2KqqtWKvPndv7y6un1F?p=preview

I've also demonstrated setting initial values in your dropdowns that will remove that annoying "blank" option.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the answer from this link http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/get-selected-value-from-a-select/20241